# OMP reduction for loop with std::map

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, stdmap

I want to parallelise the following for loop with a std::map with OpenMP 4.0:

```
int n=5000;
int nbin;

std::map<int, int> histogram;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        {
            .
            .
            nbin =....... \\some calculation with integer result 
            ++histogram[nbin];
            

        }
```

I tried before the for loop:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(                     \
                              +:std::map<int, int> :   \
                              omp_out += omp_in      \
                             )      initializer(omp_priv = 0)                    
                            
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : histogram)
```

But it gives the error:
no viable conversion from 'int' to 'std::map<int, int>'

How would be the correct reduction statement?

thanks for help!

Comment: Could it be that your `initailzier` is the whole problem? You should initialize with an empty map, not with zero.

Comment: Merging maps is generally slow. What is the values range? Cannot you just use an array? Sorting can be faster regarding the range. Please provide more information.

Comment: Other comment: how do you get `+=` defined on maps? I don't think you can do that.

Comment: The range for nbin is 0 to 60. The range of histogram[nbin] is 0 to 10.000.000

Comment: @JérômeRichard The only map merging is done in the final treewise combination of the local maps. So with a smallish map, and probably not a lot of threads, this should be a feasible approach, not?

Comment: I used now the initializer initializer(omp_priv = std::map<int, int>{}). But stil omp_out += omp_in gives an error. But i dont need to add maps i only need ++histogram[nbin], which counts up one field of the map, if the nbin is hit.

Comment: Consider using at least an std::unordered_map which should be a bit faster. Flatten hash_map should be far faster but they are sadly not implemented in the STL. If I understand your part comment correctly, you can even use a basic array to perform the histogram and it would be even faster. Using an array should be at least 1 order of magnitude faster. IPC micro-optimizations should speed up this even more.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Yeah, I did not know the histogram was so small. Still, I think using a std::map for this is overkill but that does not change the parallelization method much.

Comment: "omp_out += omp_in gives an error." Yes. You are not allowed to define `+=` for built-in types. That's why I made a class that inherits from `map` and then define that operator for that class. And indeed you don't need a map: a `map<int,int>` is a simple array.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I had initially missed that the OP was using a `map<int,int>` which can indeed simpler be done with a mere array. But I had fun figuring out how to do a reduction on maps, just in case the application actually requires a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, toy example counting characters in a string:

```
  string text{"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"};

  charcounter<char,int> charcount;
#pragma omp declare reduction\
  (     \
        +:charcounter<char,int>:omp_out += omp_in       \
        ) \
  initializer( omp_priv = charcounter<char,int>{} )

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : charcount)
  for ( int i=0; i<text.size(); i++ ) {
    char c = text[i];
    charcount.inc(c);
  }
```

(I think I can probably make that `inc` function look more like your `++foo[k]`, but that's for later.)

Implementation of the `charcounter` class, which is basically a map:

```
template<typename key,typename value>
class charcounter : public map<key,value> {
public:
  void operator+=( const charcounter<key,value>& other ) {
    for ( auto [k,v] : other )
      if ( this->contains(k) )
        this->at(k) += v;
      else
        this->insert( {k,v} );
  };
  void inc(char k) {
    if ( this->contains(k) )
      this->at(k) += 1;
    else
      this->insert( {k,1} );
  };
};
```

Note that this only demonstrates that it is possible to do a reduction on a map. Performance may dictate you using a totally different solution.

Comment: Thank you for your example, but in my case adont nedd to add maps i only need to increment one field of the map. (++histogram[nbin]) if nbin is hit. Maybe i should replace omp_out += omp_in with something that represents this increment of the field.

Comment: No. the increment of one field is the `charcount.inc(c);` statement in the loop. The `omp_out += omp_in` is where OpenMP combines the partial maps of the threads. So that means merging complete maps. Look at it this way: by doing a reduction on a map, 1. you give each thread an individual map 2. you tell OMP that after the loop the threads need to combine these individual maps. Yet another way: you seem to think that `omp_out += omp_in` is something that is done during the map construction. It's not. It's done in a loop of length number-of-threads *after* your map-construction loop.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem now with a vector and the parallelization works fine:

```
int n=5000;
int nbin;
int nrbins = 60;

std::vector<int> histogram(nrbins);
std::fill(histogram.begin(), histogram.end(), 0);

#pragma omp declare reduction(+ : std::vector<int> : \
std::transform(omp_out.begin(), omp_out.end(), omp_in.begin(), omp_out.begin(), std::plus<int>())) \
                    initializer(omp_priv = decltype(omp_orig)(omp_orig.size()))

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+ : histogram)

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        {
            .
            .
            nbin =....... \\some calculation with integer result 
            histogram[nbin]+=1;
            

        }
```

Its 3 times faster than a map even without parallelization
and with parallelization its much faster also.